# Angular 5: ERROR: Error false -- what is this?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting a bizarre error, can't find anything online related to it when I search the error. Anyone experienced this before? It only happens on page load of a certain page.

[image]

My current setup:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    //...

    {
        path: ':username',
        loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'
    }
];

export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**user-routing.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { UserComponent } from './user.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: UserComponent
    }
];

export const UserRoutingModule = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**user.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'user',
    templateUrl: './user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent {

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        // ...
    ) {
        route.params.subscribe(params => {
            // ...
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please copy the text of the error, an image is not readable by everyone, and prevents the text from being selected by others as well.